# Getting Image element from raw HTML

Tags: image, gwt, jsni

My app create popUp through SafeHTMLBuilder. I want to add Click handler (resize onClick) to this img.

I know that if I use uiBinder i can add ui:field tag:

```
   @UiField
   Image 
   ...
    image.addClickhandler(...);
```

In my case I think I should use JSNI but I dont imagine how it looks.

```
SafeHtmlBuilder html = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    html.appendHtmlConstant("<div class=\"detailsPopup\">")
        .append(TEMPLATES.image(record.getImageUrl()))
        .appendHtmlConstant("</div>")
```

Template of image

```
  @Template("<img id=\"img\" src=\"{0}\"/>")
   SafeHtml image(String url);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the popup that you build using SafeHTMBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [Label.wrap()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html). Your code would look something like this (not tested)

> ```
>  Element element = new Element();
>  element.setInnerSafeHtml(html.toSafeHtml());
>  Label label = new Label();
>  label.wrap(element);
>  label.addClickHandler....
> ```

Or simply use [GwtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) like this

> ```
> $("#detailsPopup").click(new Function() { 
>  public boolean f(Event e){
>     Window.alert("This is GWT code without widget baggage!");
>      return true;
>   }
> });
> ```